# Nan display total React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a simple inventory management System.when i enter the price and qty selected event total need to be calculate. but i couldn't correct total what i tried so far i attached below please see the code and give me the solution for it.
**Form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Price" 
    value={price}
    onChange={handlePriceChange}
  
    />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Qty</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Qty" 
    value={qty}
    onChange={handleQuantityChange}

    />
```

**Total**

```
   const calculateTotal = () => {
      const newTotal = price * qty;
      setSum(newTotal);
    };
  
    // Event handler for price input
    const handlePriceChange = (e) => {
      const newPrice = parseFloat(e.target.value);
      setPrice(newPrice);
     
    };
  
    // Event handler for quantity selection
    const handleQuantityChange = (e) => {
      const newQuantity = parseInt(e.target.value);
      setQty(newQuantity);
      calculateTotal();
    };
```

Comment: Why do you need total as state? Just use it as a regular variable: const total = qty * price. Not everything should be state, you already have qty and price, so you can calculate the total, no need new state for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize price and qty using useState with initial values.

```
 const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
 const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);
 const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
```

You can use isNaN() to ensure that price and qty are numeric values and not empty or invalid before performing the calculation

```
 // Event handler for price input
 const handlePriceChange = (e) => {
const newPrice = parseFloat(e.target.value);
if (!isNaN(newPrice)) {
  setPrice(newPrice);
  calculateTotal(newPrice, qty);
}
};

// Event handler for quantity selection
 const handleQuantityChange = (e) => {
 const newQuantity = parseInt(e.target.value);
 if (!isNaN(newQuantity)) {
  setQty(newQuantity);
  calculateTotal(price, newQuantity);
  }
  };

 // Calculate the total based on price and quantity
 const calculateTotal = (price, qty) => {
const newTotal = price * qty;
setTotal(newTotal);
 };
```

Comment: but when i change the qty total not displayed shown as empty